# maps file empty for some processes

Tags: linux, process

In the `/proc` file system, why is that some files have their `maps` file empty. Is it because no memory has been allocated to them or the data isn't available?

They must be allocated some memory, otherwise how are they running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that all the pseudo-files `/proc/1234/maps` and `/proc/self/maps` have always a zero size, as reported by the [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall and the `ls` command. However, they are sequentially readable (e.g. by the `cat` command, or with [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) syscall, e.g. called by `fgets`). Try `cat /proc/self/maps` and `ls -ls /proc/self/maps` for example.

<sup>A probable reason for the `/proc/*/maps` files to have a 0 size is that computing their size means computing their content, and that could be expensive. So the kernel prefers to say 0 for their size. Think of them as being sort of pipes. You need to read them sequentially, they are not [lseek(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html)-able.</sup>

Read the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for details about `/proc/`; notice that it is using Unix permissions and ownership, so you cannot access a `/proc/1234` directory if the process of pid 1234 is not yours.

And you might also have some [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). These don't have any address space anymore, so I won't be surprised if their `maps` pseudo-file in `/proc` is truly empty (in the sense that reading it gives immediately an end-of-file condition), or even missing.

Remember that files under `/proc` are pseudo-files, in the sense that the kernel is providing them (and giving their data), and they don't involve any real disk I/O. In particular, reading them should be fast.